# How to fix: "Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference"

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am making a simple encoder/decoder for me and my friend to talk to each other in code, or at least it should be simple. I keep getting the error "Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference" when I try to reference any of my elements. I feel like I am doing something really dumb that is simple to fix, but I can't see it.

I have looked at several related questions already and have been trying a bunch of stuff that has been suggested, but nothing seems to work. By the way, I am using Microsoft Edge if that makes a difference.

```js
var inMsg = document.getElementById("input")
var outMsg = document.getElementById("output")

document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
  if (event.key == 'Enter') {
    try {
      event.preventDefault()
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
    try {
      console.log(inMsg.value)

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="./main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h2>Paste Coded Message Here -></h2>
    <textarea id="input" value=""></textarea>

    <textarea id="output"></textarea>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Usually I am able to just log the value no problem, but it says the element is null when I console.log it.

Comment: When is your script run? It it run after the page is done rendering, or might it run before then? What happens if you look up the elements inside the event listener instead of earlier?

Comment: put your script tag at the end of the document, that will work for now...
For details see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup

Comment: As an alternative to what @AxelM said you can use DOMContentLoaded event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `defer` to your script tag like so:

```
<script src="./main.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
```

I believe the html parser hasn't reached your `inMsg` element by the time the script is executed and so the value of the element is `undefined`.

Let me know if that works!

Comment: Glad to help! Basically, html is read top to bottom and `<script>` tags are executed immediately, meaning they block the html from continuing to load until after the JavaScript has finished executing. If you add `defer` attribute, the script is executed after html document has been fully "loaded." Finally, if you add `async` tag, the script will execute at the same time html continues to parse (i.e. asynchronously). Anytime your script depends on an element existing in the DOM, you should ensure that the script tag is located below the element in the html file or that you are using defer.

Answer (score 0):

Move the first two lines into the add event listener function. This function might called before the dom is ready and isMag variable filled with null.